# Sum of duplicate values with multiple values in hash

Tags: ruby

Given a hash that looks like the following:

```
h = {
  "0" => ["1", "true", "21"],
  "1" => ["2", "true", "21"],
  "2" => ["3", "false", "21"],
  "3" => ["4", "true", "22"],
  "4" => ["5", "true", "22"],
  "5" => ["6", "true", "22"],
  "6" => ["7", "false", "21"]
}
```

I want to find the sum of elements at position `0` across arrays that have the same elements at indices `1` and `2`, and return a hash like the following:

```
{
  0 => ["3", "true", "21"],
  1 => ["10", "false", "21"],
  2 => ["15", "true", "22"]
}
```

Since there are two arrays with indices `1` and `2` having values `"true"` and `"21"`, I want to sum the integer values of index `0` for those two arrays, for example.

How can I convert the example hash at the top of this question to the resultant hash below it?

Comment: I've read this multiple times and I'm really struggling to understand your example and what your goal is. I also don't see anything you've done to try to solve this on your own. I recommend you take a step back, rethink the problem, and explain it as clearly as you can, keeping in mind [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @anothermh I appreciate the feedback and i tried very hard to be clear about this. I have read over the how to ask a good question in the past. My attempts haven't gotten anywhere besides breaking down the key and value.. To be more helpful [2,b,c] [4,b,c][1,c,d] so i would want to add the first and second array together and get [6,b,c][1,c,d]

Comment: I have done my best to clean up your question based on my understanding of it and have left an answer below. Feel free to revert my edits if they don't align with what your actual question is.

Comment: When you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to all input values. Here that might be `h = { "0" => ...}`. That way, readers can refer to those variables in comments and answers without having to define them.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the person who commented before you edited this post for me because the way I was trying to explain it before was unorganized. I did have value there though lol

Comment: Have a look on answer I provided, it is simplest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
def group_em(h)    
  h.group_by { |_,v| v.drop(1) }.
    transform_values do |a|
      a.transpose.
        last.
        map(&:first).
        sum(&:to_i).
        to_s
    end.
    each_with_index.
    with_object({}) { |((a,v),i),g| g[i] = [v,*a] }
end
```

**Example**

```
h = {
  "0" => ["1", "true",  "21"],
  "1" => ["2", "true",  "21"],
  "2" => ["3", "false", "21"],
  "3" => ["4", "true",  "22"],
  "4" => ["5", "true",  "22"],
  "5" => ["6", "true",  "22"],
  "6" => ["7", "false", "21"]
}

group_em(h)
  #=> {0=>["3",  "true",  "21"],
  #    1=>["10", "false", "21"],
  #    2=>["15", "true",  "22"]}
```

**Explanation**

*The major steps*

For the hash `h` above the major steps are as follows.

```
p = h.group_by { |_,v| v.drop(1) }
  #=> {["true",  "21"]=>[["0", ["1", "true",  "21"]],
  #                      ["1", ["2", "true",  "21"]]],
  #    ["false", "21"]=>[["2", ["3", "false", "21"]],
  #                      ["6", ["7", "false", "21"]]],
  #    ["true",  "22"]=>[["3", ["4", "true",  "22"]],
  #                      ["4", ["5", "true",  "22"]],
  #                      ["5", ["6", "true",  "22"]]]}
q = p.transform_values do |a|
      a.transpose.
        last.
        map(&:first).
        sum(&:to_i).
        to_s
    end
  #=> {["true", "21"]=>"3", ["false", "21"]=>"10", ["true", "22"]=>"15"}
enum0 = q.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: {["true", "21"]=>"3", ["false", "21"]=>"10",
  #     ["true", "22"]=>"15"}:each_with_index>
enum1 = enum0.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: {["true", "21"]=>"3", ["false", "21"]=>"10",
  #     ["true", "22"]=>"15"}:each_with_index>:with_object({})>
enum1.each { |((a,v),i),g| g[i] = [v,*a] }
  #=> {0=>["3", "true", "21"],
  #    1=>["10", "false", "21"],
  #    2=>["15", "true", "22"]}
```

We can see the values that will be generated and passed to the block by by the enumerator `enum1` by converting it to an array:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[[[["true", "21"], "3"], 0], []],
  #    [[[["false", "21"], "10"], 1], []],
  #    [[[["true", "22"], "15"], 2], []]]
```

If you compare the return value for `enum0` with that of `enum1` you can think of the latter as a *compound enumerator*, though Ruby does not employ that term.

*Details of `Hash#transform_values`*

Now let's look more closely at the calculation of `q`. The first value of `p` is passed to the block by [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) (which made its debut in MRI 2.4) and becomes the value of the block variable `a`:

```
a = p.first.last
  #=> [["0", ["1", "true", "21"]], ["1", ["2", "true", "21"]]]
```

The block calculations are as follows.

```
b = a.transpose
  #=> [["0", "1"], [["1", "true", "21"], ["2", "true", "21"]]]
c = b.last
  #=> [["1", "true", "21"], ["2", "true", "21"]]
d = c.map(&:first) # ~same as c.map { |a| a.first }
  #=> ["1", "2"] 
e = e.sum(&:to_i)  # ~same as e.sum { |s| s.to_i }
  #=> 3
e.to_s
  #=> "3"
```

We see that the value `a` has been transformed to `"3"`. The remaining calculations to compute `q` are similar.

*Documentation links*

You can find documentation for the methods I've used at the following links for classes [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html) (`drop`, `transpose`, `last`, `first` and `sum`), [Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html) (`to_s`), [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html) (`to_i`) and [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html) (`with_object` and `next`), and the module [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html) (`group_by`, `map` and `each_with_index`).

*Decomposition of nested objects*

There is one more tricky-bit I would like to mention. That is the line

```
enum1.each { |((a,v),i),g| g[i] = [v,*a] }
```

I've written the block variables in such a way to decompose the values that are generated by the enumerator `enum1` and passed to the block. I'm sure that it must look quite imposing for a newbie, but it's not so bad if you take step-by-step, as I will explain.

Firstly, suppose I had a single block variable `r` (`enum1.each { |r|...}`). The first value is generated and passed to the block, assigning a value to `r`:

```
r = enum1.next
  #=> [[[["true", "21"], "3"], 0], []]
```

We could then execute the following statement in the block to decompose (of *disambiguate*) `r` as follows:

```
((a,v),i),g = r
  #=> [[[["true", "21"], "3"], 0], []]
```

producing the following assignments:

```
a #=> ["true", "21"]
v #=> "3"
i #=> 0
g #=> []
```

It is equivalent, and simpler, to replace `|r|` in the block with `|((a,v),i),g|`.

If you study the locations of the brackets in the nested array produced by `enum1.next` you will see how I determined where I needed parentheses when writing the block variables. This decomposition of nested arrays and other objects is a very convenient and powerful feature or Ruby, one that is much underused.

Comment: Thanks for much for doing this. I am trying to be able to think of this stuff on my own eventually! Thanks for taking the time to answer

Comment: I think you can learn a lot about both Ruby and the *Ruby-way* by trying to see how much of my code you can understand. I've provided quite a bit of detail for each step of the calculations as well as links to documentation for the methods I've used. You won't understand everything but I think you may even learn a little by osmosis from the parts that remain a mystery. Note that I've written this not just for you, but also for others who are a few weeks or months ahead of you in their quest to become proficient in the language.

Comment: Thank you for the detail in this, I am going through this line by line trying to break it down. I appreciate the time

Answer (score 2):

I am not a ruby developer so I can't suggest any best practices but simple algorithm that comes in my mind after reading this, is to create a new hash and check if array values are in it or not, if not then append new value like this.

```
h = {
  "0" => ["1", "true", "21"],
  "1" => ["2", "true", "21"],
  "2" => ["3", "false", "21"],
  "3" => ["4", "true", "22"],
  "4" => ["5", "true", "22"],
  "5" => ["6", "true", "22"],
  "6" => ["7", "false", "21"]
}

new_h = {}
h.each do |key, val|
  x1 = val.at(1)
  x2 = val.at(2)
  found = false
  new_h.each do |key1, val2|
    y1 = val2.at(1)
    y2 = val2.at(2)
    if x1 === y1 && x2 === y2
      found = true
      arr = [val2.at(0).to_i + val.at(0).to_i, x1, x2]
      new_h[key1] = arr
    end
  end
  if !found
    new_h[new_h.length] = val
  end
  if new_h.empty?
    new_h[key] = val
  end
end

puts "#{new_h}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply so much! Hope that made sense to you. I appreciate your response. I am testing it out now!

Comment: Glad to help. Please test the edited version because I wasn't converting string to int before.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity.

```
input.
  values.
  map { |i, *rest| [rest, i.to_i] }.
  group_by(&:shift).
  map do |*key, values|
    [values.flatten.sum.to_s, *key.flatten]
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

references : [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Enumerator#with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index), [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h)

```
key_sum = ->(group) { group.sum { |key, _| key.to_i }.to_s }
given_hash.values.group_by { |_, *rest| rest }. 
  map.with_index { |(key, group), idx| [idx, [key_sum.call(group), *key]] }.to_h
#=> {0=>["3", "true", "21"], 1=>["10", "false", "21"], 2=>["15", "true", "22"]}
```

- group by

  ```
  given_hash.values.group_by { |_, *rest| rest }
  #=> { ["true", "21"] => [["1", "true", "21"], ["2", "true", "21"]]...
  ```
- key_sum function

  ```
  key_sum = ->(group) { group.sum { |key, _| key.to_i }.to_s }
  key_sum.call([["1", "true", "21"], ["2", "true", "21"]]) #=> '3'
  ```
- to_h

  ```
  [[0, ["3", "true", "21"]], [1, ["10", "false", "21"]], [2, ["15", "true", "22"]]].to_h
  #=> {0=>["3", "true", "21"], 1=>["10", "false", "21"], 2=>["15", "true", "22"]}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question, despite being a very long way of solving it. I'm sure there are shortcuts to solve it more easily but you requested a clear explanation of what's happening and I hope that this guides you through how to solve it.

```
# Start with a hash
hash = {
  "0" => ["1", "true", "21"],
  "1" => ["2", "true", "21"],
  "2" => ["3", "false", "21"],
  "3" => ["4", "true", "22"],
  "4" => ["5", "true", "22"],
  "5" => ["6", "true", "22"],
  "6" => ["7", "false", "21"]
}

# Extract just the values from the hash into an array
values = hash.values

added_values = values.map do |array|
  # Find all arrays that match this array's values at indices [1] and [2]
  matching = values.select { |a| a[1] == array[1] && a[2] == array[2] }
  sum = 0
  # Add the values at index 0 from each matching array
  matching.each { |match| sum += match[0].to_i }
  # Return a new array with these values
  [sum.to_s, array[1], array[2]]
end

# Reject any duplicative arrays
added_values.uniq!

# Convert the array back to a hash
added_values.each_with_index.each_with_object({}) { |(array, index), hash| hash[index] = array }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this and answer this question. It really helps knowing different approaches to answering these questions

Answer (score 0):

**Hash** and **Array** have most powerful in-built functions in ruby.

```
z = h.group_by { |k,v| v[1..2] }.keep_if { |k,v| v.length > 1 }
val = z.map { |k,v| [v.map { |x| x[1] }.map(&:first).map(&:to_i).inject(:+).to_s, k[0], k[1]] }
val.each_with_index.inject({}) { |m,(x,i)| m[i] = x; m }

=> {0 =>["3", "true", "21"], 1 =>["10", "false", "21"], 2 =>["15", "true", "22"]}
```

If you know these functions then you do not need complex implementation ever. *Happy learning :)*

Answer (score 0):

```
h
.values
.group_by{|_, *a| a}
.map
.with_index{|(k, a), i| [i, [a.inject(0){|acc, (n, *)| acc + n.to_i}.to_s, *k]]}
.to_h
# => {0=>["3", "true", "21"], 1=>["10", "false", "21"], 2=>["15", "true", "22"]}
```